# 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

My use case is as follows. I need to be able to call java methods from within python code

from py spark this seems to be very easy

I start the py spark like this
           ./pyspark --driver-class-path /path/to/app.jar

and from pyspark shell do this

```
        x=sc._jvm.com.abc.def.App
        x.getMessage()
        u'Hello'
        x.getMessage()
        u'Hello'
```

This works fine.

When working with spark job server though:

I use the WordCountSparkJob.py example shipped

```
from sparkjobserver.api import SparkJob, build_problems
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, java_import

class WordCountSparkJob(SparkJob):

def validate(self, context, runtime, config):
    if config.get('input.strings', None):
        return config.get('input.strings')
    else:
        return build_problems(['config input.strings not found'])

def run_job(self, context, runtime, data):
    x = context._jvm.com.abc.def.App        
    return x.getMessage()
```

My python.conf looks like this

```
spark {
jobserver {
jobdao = spark.jobserver.io.JobSqlDAO
}

context-settings {
python {
paths = [
"/home/xxx/SPARK/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python",
"/home/xxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhocon",
"/home/xxx/SPARK/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip",
"/home/xxx/SPARK/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",
"/home/xxx/gitrepos/spark-jobserver/job-server-python/src/python    /dist/spark_jobserver_python-NO_ENV-py2.7.egg"
]
}
dependent-jar-uris = ["file:///path/to/app.jar"]
}
home = /home/path/to/spark
}
```

I get the following error

```
    [2016-10-08 23:03:46,214] ERROR jobserver.python.PythonJob []         [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/py-context] - From Python: Error while calling 'run_job'TypeError("'JavaPackage' object is not callable",)
[2016-10-08 23:03:46,226] ERROR jobserver.python.PythonJob [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/py-context] - Python job failed with error code 4
[2016-10-08 23:03:46,228] ERROR .jobserver.JobManagerActor []     [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/py-context] - Got Throwable
    java.lang.Exception: Python job failed with error code 4
    at spark.jobserver.python.PythonJob$$anonfun$1.apply(PythonJob.scala:85)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at spark.jobserver.python.PythonJob.runJob(PythonJob.scala:62)
    at spark.jobserver.python.PythonJob.runJob(PythonJob.scala:13)
    at     spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-10-08 23:03:46,232] ERROR .jobserver.JobManagerActor [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/py-context] - Exception from job 942727f0-dd81-445d-bc64-bd18880eb4bc:
java.lang.Exception: Python job failed with error code 4
at spark.jobserver.python.PythonJob$$anonfun$1.apply(PythonJob.scala:85)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at spark.jobserver.python.PythonJob.runJob(PythonJob.scala:62)
at spark.jobserver.python.PythonJob.runJob(PythonJob.scala:13)
at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-10-08 23:03:46,232] INFO k.jobserver.JobStatusActor [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/py-context/$a] - Job 942727f0-dd81-445d-bc64-bd18880eb4bc finished with an error
[2016-10-08 23:03:46,233] INFO r$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef [] [akka://JobServer/deadLetters] - Message [spark.jobserver.CommonMessages$JobErroredOut] from Actor[akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/py-context/$a#1919442151] to Actor[akka://JobServer/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

In the python.conf file I have the app.jar as an entry in dependent-jar-uris.
Am I missing something here

Comment: - From Python: Error while calling 'run_job'TypeError("'JavaPackage' object is not callable",)

Comment: Have the same error. Appreciate for any hints.

Answer (score 3):

Error `"'JavaPackage' object is not callable"` probably means that PySpark cannot see your jar or your class in it.